# How to customize Material UI Chip component to be editable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to use [Material UI - Chip](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-chip/) in a simple Todo App. By adding `onDelete` attribute, we can make it deletable.

```js
<Chip label="Deletable" onDelete={handleDelete} />
```

[image: A deletable chip]

But my desired task chips should also be `editable`, and allow user to toggle when it is done.

[image: My task chip]

The event handlers `handleEdit` and `handleToggleDone` are all prepared. But how can I add them to the `Chip` component?

Comment: It seems to me that the Chip component doesn't have an API that would fit with your usecase. You may need to consider some other existing component or create a new component in your application.

Comment: @Jokinen yeah, ended up create one on my own.